# Inconsistencies when trying redef functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm playing around with Clojure's `with-redefs-fn`, and I'm seeing some puzzling inconsistencies. For example:

```
(with-redefs-fn {#'println (constantly nil)} #(println "foo"))
=> nil
```

As expected, `println` no longer has any effect, just eval'ing to `nil`. However, in:

```
(with-redefs-fn {#'= (constantly false)} #(= 1 1))
=> true

(with-redefs-fn {#'+ (constantly 0)} #(+ 1 1))
=> 2

(with-redefs-fn {#'max (constantly 1)} #(max 1 2))
=> 2
```

We no longer see the expected behavior, the redef'd functions appear to be operating as usual. My suspicion is that these particular simple functions are being optimized out for bytecode ops and are thus unaffected by the redef'ing. Can anyone confirm this as it's been puzzling me for a while.

Interestingly, if you refer to the var but not in the function invocation position you get the redefined value:

```
user=> (with-redefs-fn {#'= (constantly false)} #(constantly =))
#object[clojure.core$constantly$fn__5672 0x72458efc "clojure.core$constantly$fn__5672@72458efc"]
user=> =
#object[clojure.core$_EQ_ 0x2caf6912 "clojure.core$_EQ_@2caf6912"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to inlining:

```
(defn not-inlined [arg]
  (println "Won't be inlined"))

(defn inlined
  {:inline (fn [a] `(println "Was inlined!" ~a))}
  [arg]
  (println "Wasn't inlined!"))


(with-redefs-fn {#'not-inlined (constantly "REDEFINED!")}
  #(println (not-inlined 1)))
=> REDEFINED!

(with-redefs-fn {#'inlined (constantly "REDEFINED!")}
  #(println (inlined 1)))
=> Was inlined! 1
```

`println` is not inlined, while `=`, `+`, and `max` are. I'm not *entirely* sure how inlining works, but if the entire function is literally replaced by the supplied body, `inlined` won't exist to be redefined.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if you refer to the var but not in the function invocation position you get the redefined value:

```
user=> (with-redefs-fn {#'= (constantly false)} #(constantly =)) 
#object[clojure.core$constantly$fn__5672 0x72458efc"clojure.core$constantly$fn__5672@72458efc"]
user=> =
#object[clojure.core$_EQ_ 0x2caf6912 "clojure.core$_EQ_@2caf6912"
```

Which makes it definitely not a "length of the argument list" problem. Definitely seems like some sort of inlining optimisation.

Yeah, inlining: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L976

```
user=> (with-redefs-fn {#'compare (constantly false)} #(compare 0 1))
-1
```

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L830